# Safari Select Won't Open

Tags: html, safari, osx-yosemite, selectlist

Given a simple select list.

```
<select>
    <option>Test 1</option>
    <option>Test 2</option>
    <option>Test 3</option>
    <option>Test 4</option>
</select>
```

Running Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gbdvn2ht/

1. Open Page in Safari (8.0.8 or earlier I presume, it works as expected in OSX 10.11)
2. Observe that clicking quickly over and over on the select list opens the select list and selects the first item.
3. Focus on another window (I used a terminal but it doesn't matter)
4. While focused on the other window click back into the Safari tab but make sure you click directly on the select and continue clicking quickly.
5. Observe that the select initial opens, closes, and then stops responding. A  page refresh of the page is the only way to make it work again. Clicking on it no longer opens the select list.

Strange right?

Given the fact that the newest Safari doesn't present the problem I can assume it's a Safari bug. However, I still need to support this version of the browser. Any ideas on a workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why you are concerned about this. What are the odds of a user doing that? If it's a bug, there isn't a likely fix that will not end up costing you in some other way.

Comment: I have a copy of Safari 8.0.7 and would be happy to send it via the internet to anyone who needs a copy for testing. I will test this later on my mac ;)

Comment: Couple of things here - Safari 8 is out of date and people should be using Safari 9. It's available on both Yosemite and El Capitan so you don't need to update your OS to use Safari 9. Next, this is a bug with Safari, and probably can't be fixed. Finally, are people _really_ going to do that sequence of actions?

Comment: I have tested this on Yosemite 10.10.5 and Safari 9.0.1. It seems to be working fine there but I am not sure if my clicking ability matches up to yours =D Cheers.

Comment: Same strange behaviour in Safari 6.2.6

Comment: @www139 it's actually more likely than you might think. The actual web app is inside an embedded webkitview and it occurs when someone is focusing off of a native window back to the webview.

Comment: @towerofnix it's actually more likely than you might think. The actual web app is inside an embedded WKWebView and it occurs when someone is focusing off of a native window back to the webview.

Comment: @alp yeah it seems to work in Safari 9 and up. Clicking skills not really required, just easiest way to get it to happen.

Comment: Since Safari 9.0 is available for 10.10, I suppose I'll just have to let this go since it's obviously a Safari Bug.

Comment: @jab I tested your jsfiddle following the steps in Safari 8.0.7 on OS X 10.11.1 and I didn't experience the problem. It could be because I am using two different Safaris at once, but I wouldn't know why. Maybe it's a bug in only Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to that version of Safari, but have you tried using a jquery plugin to override the drop down ?  I thought it would be worth a shot.

I've updated the jsfiddle for you to try.

http://jsfiddle.net/gbdvn2ht/1/

The plugin I tried was Select2 (https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

```
$("#select").select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
});
```

Comment: I really don't want a plugin if i can help it. The web app is actually in a native wrapper and the native dropdown functionality allows certain behaviors like going outside of the web browser container and flows over other native elements in the app.